# routerLink directive does not set the href attribute when used used on an <area> element

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am trying to navigate to the new page on clicking on the area element but nothing happens. If I same apply to `<a></a>` tag it works like as intended.

**HTML**

```
<area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126"
          routerLink="/help"
          target="_blank" alt="Circle" />
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, 
  RouterModule.forRoot([
    {
      path: '',
      component: HelloComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'help',
      component: HelpComponent
    }
  ])],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent, HelpComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I am using Angular 7.0.1.

Comment: if its not working you can try using the `(click)` event handler instead, and use `Router` service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check the below stackblitz, maybe you missed adding the surrounding components for `area` element.

Below is the html wrapping the `area` element.

```
<img usemap="#infographic" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/mdn-info2.png" alt="MDN infographic" />
<map name="infographic">
    <area shape="poly" coords="130,147,200,107,254,219,130,228"
          routerLink="/help" alt="HTML" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="130,147,130,228,6,219,59,107"
          routerLink="/docs/Web/CSS"
          target="_blank" alt="CSS" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="130,147,200,107,130,4,59,107"
          routerLink="/docs/Web/JavaScript"
          target="_blank" alt="JavaScript" />
</map>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The router-outlet was missing in the updated stack blitz from the user, on click of the middle area element navigation happens!

<kbd>**StackBlitz**</kbd>

Comment: Please check this my stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9wezma?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts nothing is happening when I click on js